# what does "fast" or "normal" mean in "free(): invalid next size (fast)"?

Tags: c++, c

What does "fast" or "normal" mean in  "free(): invalid next size (fast)": can anyone explain what this means/implies or where to find the answer?

Comment: If this is a runtime error you are getting it sounds like you are double deleting a pointer.  You should try to create a [mcve] to help you find where in your code this is coming from

Comment: Read through the implementation of Glibc if you want the detailed answer [fast](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html#4199) [normal](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html#4272).

Comment: @Mankarse thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Note for close-voters:  this question is specifically about what the "fast" vs "normal" part of the error message means -- in particular it's not asking why the error appears, or how to debug a program that prints this message.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're seeing indicates an internal bookkeeping error when managing dynamically allocated memory.  It's typically caused by an application writing outside the bounds of allocated memory or performing a double free.

So your program is stepping on memory it shouldn't be.  If you run your code through [valgrind](http://valgrind.org), it should tell you exactly where.